# adding object dynamically in live a-frame camera view

Tags: aframe

> I am trying to place an image in **`a-frame`** camera view.  please share an example.

Comment: You should add your code to explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to add an invisible "marker" as a child of the camera, and use its position as the spawn point when adding an object.

HTML

```
<a-scene>
  <a-camera>
    <a-entity id="marker" position="0 0 -5"></a-entity>
  </a-camera>
  <a-cylinder id="floor" height="0.1" radius="10" color="green"></a-cylinder>
</a-scene>
```

JS

```
var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
var markerEl = document.querySelector('#marker');

// Add boxe when spacebar is pressed.
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode !== 32) return;

  var newEl = document.createElement('a-box');
  newEl.setAttribute('color', 'red');
  sceneEl.appendChild(newEl);
  var position = markerEl.object3D.getWorldPosition();
  position.y = 0.5;
  newEl.setAttribute('position', position);
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/donmccurdy/pen/QOOXbK?editors=1010